# 2-dimensional interpolation

Tags: c++, python, math

I want to find a value of z at y = 12 and x = 3.5, given the below example data. How can I do this in C++?

```
y = 10
x = [1,2, 3,4, 5,6]
z = [2.3, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 9.6, 11.2]

y = 20 
x = [1,2, 3,4, 5,6]
z = [4.3, 5.4, 7.6, 9.8, 11.6, 13.2]

y = 30 
x = [1,2, 3,4, 5,6]
z = [6.3, 7.4, 8.6, 10.8, 13.6, 15.2]
```

---

My current Python code:

```
import scipy
import math
import numpy
from scipy import interpolate

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [10, 20, 30]

Y = numpy.array([[i]*len(x) for i in y])
X = numpy.array([x for i in y])
Z = numpy.array([[2.3, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 9.6, 11.2],
                 [4.3, 5.4, 7.6, 9.8, 11.6, 13.2],
                 [6.3, 7.4, 8.6, 10.8, 13.6, 15.2]]) 


tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X, Y, Z)
print interpolate.bisplev(3.5, 15, tck)
```

Comment: There are many algorithms you could use. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#2_dimensions Do you have a preference?

Comment: no .. i have this implemented in python i have to implement it in c++
this is a sample i provided from my database 
my Y varies from 0 - 300 in steps of 10
my X from 1 - 20
and corresponding 20 values of data on Z axis 
Which one you suggest or how to go about it

Comment: Show us your python implementation, and where you're stuck turning it into C++.

Comment: import scipy


import math


import numpy


from scipy import interpolate




x= [1,2,3,4,5,6]


y= [10,20,30]



Y = numpy.array([[i]*len(x) for i in y])


X = numpy.array([x for i in y])


Z = numpy.array([[2.3,3.4,5.6,7.8,9.6,11.2],
                 [4.3,5.4,7.6,9.8,11.6,13.2],
                 [6.3,7.4,8.6,10.8,13.6,15.2]]) 



tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X,Y,Z)


print interpolate.bisplev(3.5,15,tck)

Comment: THis is my python code 

I am starter at c++ so 
interpolate.bisplrep how to get it in C++ is the question

Comment: Put the pythin code into the question so we can read it.

Comment: Also, select the code and press the *01010* button to mark it as code and make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the interpolation twice. First interpolate with Y to select the two Z tables. Then interpolate with X to pick the Z value.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Akima's Spline](http://www.recnet.com/fortran/itplbv.for), which is very well-tested, very fast, and produces extremely good results.

Unfortunately, it's in Fortran-66 (and messy at that), so you'll need to either translate it to C or a more modern variant of Fortran. I've [gotten some help](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.fortran/browse_thread/thread/516bf3a84932176e/754e9b3a3efcda3e) in getting it all to work, so I'd suggest reading through [my](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?hl=en&enc_user=3o_mIBkAAAAhFwwBkBq9VP28ZiU6ZncOhacXVizsW-Jc5A0U8nfmbA) [threads](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/browse_thread/thread/cff8acc5c6cee589/9452cc802c8b1d41) on Usenet.

Comment: see my list of Akima Spline implementations at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502769/akima-interpolation-of-an-array-of-doubles/4637884#4637884